# Multiple private DNS zones for different domains in the same AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have read some of the AWS documents but could not find an exact answer. I am looking to have different domains resolving internally inside the same VPC.

Something like this:

```
domain1.internal (dns zone Z1)
domain2.internal (dns zone Z2)
```

Both domains would obviously resolve hosts in the same ip ranges.

Is this possible in AWS and are any potential clashes or pitfalls having this configuration?

Or should I have a single private DNS zone instead as below?

```
subdomain1.domain.internal
subdomain2.domain.internal
```

Comment: I haven't tried this specific setup (multiple sub-domains), so not an answer, but it should work. Each domain requires its own hosted zone in Route53. Where things might get tricky is creating the sub-domain relationships: you'll have to create a hosted zone for the top-level domain, and and NS records for the sub-domains. But I don't see any reason why that won't work.

Comment: Are you delegating Name Servers for each subdomain? If not, then you can create one Hosted Zone. Subdomains do not require their own zones. I usually do not create delegated zones except when the zone is large or I want separate/independant management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default AWS uses Route 53 for domain resolution. Route 53 provides Private Hosted Zones for internal domains. Private Hosted Zones are tied to VPCs, so they they will resolve domains in the same CIDR ranges.

When you create a Private Hosted Zone, you specify a parent domain. Each hosted zone can have different type of [records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html). NS records are generated by AWS, you don't have to create them manually. In case of other records:

- You can have an `A` record, which can be either Alias or non-Alias. This can be the same as the domain name of the hosted zone;
- You can multiple `CNAME` records or 'A' records for your subdomains;
- You can have other records, for other purposes (see record [types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html) )

In your case if we take `subdomain1.domain.internal` and `subdomain2.domain.internal`:

- You can have `domain.internal` as the parent record for the hosted zone and create 2 `CNAME` or `A` records for `subdomain1` and `subdomain2`
- Or you can create separate hosted zones for `subdomain1.domain.internal` and `subdomain2.domain.internal` and use `A` records

The downfall of the first approach is that your hosted zones wont be as granular, meaning that everything which ends with `domain.internal` will be resolved with this hosted zone. You can override this, by creating other hosted zones with more precise parent domain names (see [overlapping namespaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zone-private-considerations.html)).

The downfall of the second approach is that you will pay for each hosted zone. Private Hosted Zones are relatively cheap.

Comment: Edit: I did a correction to use `subdomain1.domain.internal` and `subdomain2.domain.internal` as an example, for better understanding. The same can be applied if you create the hosted zone with `internal` as the parent domain.